# Should I prime old exposed plaster before repairing it?

Tags: plaster, patching-drywall, primer, drywall-mud

Paint peeled in a few areas I'm assuming from bad prep many years back, and no primer. Should I go ahead and sand/prime these areas before mudding and repairing? The exposed plaster is super slick and very smooth.  Sorry if this is a subjective question, I'm simply trying to understand IF primer is recommended before repair, or just go straight to mud coat (Easy Sand Joint Setting Compound, or Plus 3 Pre-Mixed Compound) and then prime after.

This surface is going to be painted with a standard 3/8" nap roller after to give it a slight roller texture, so it won't be left as smooth as the plaster is, and instead will have roller texture.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Well, if the surface is very smooth, you can't expect anything to stick to it, it's like trying to mud or paint a piece of glass. It needs to be roughed up simply so the next layer can engage.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Great point. So would I sand it to rough it up, then mud it? Or sand and prime, then mud in this case?

Comment: Well the mud doesn't need primer to attach to the old surface.  You only really need primer under paint.  I don't like putting primer under anything but paint unless they are similar chemistries.

Comment: gotta agree with @Harper-ReinstateMonica  it needs to be roughed up.  Get Vinny and Guido to "rough it up"!  Sorry, couldn't resist.  Anyway, some 60 grit or 80 grit on a 1/4 sheet sander should get the job done in no time. I've found that mud sticks to about anything, but roughing it up just a bit will give it some teeth to hang onto.   Fix first, plaster, prime and paint later.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Thanks for the extra info on grit and all. I'm going to give this a go. I used Easy Sand joint setting hot mud in my own home years back on all my plaster repairs and it bonded fine, but I don't recall finding anything this glass smooth.  Would you use easy sand joint compound/hot mud for your first coat in this case to get a good bond? I think I'm going to do hot mud for the 1st fill in coat, then I'll use Plus 3 or an all purpose type of premixed mud for the final fill and feathering stages.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thanks for that extra info as well. So rough it up and mud away, that's the plan.

Comment: @RocketManZ  Don't over-think this. Just mud it over with a finishing mud, doesn't need to be "hot mud" unless you are in  a big hurry.  Frankly Ive had some issues with hot mud in the way of setting too fast and cracking.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson 60 or 80 grit? That sounds _overly_ aggressive. Are you sure? (not an expert, asking for a friend ;)

Comment: @FreeMan  I maintain that 60 or 80 grit is fine. You want to give the surface some teeth for the mud to connect with.  Any sanding marks will be filled completely with the first coat of mud.

Answer (score 1):

`Paint peeled in a few areas`

indication you will have to sand the surface.

Using Drywall specific grit paper, and covering large area then already visible peeling, since there might be already many micro cracks in the paint.

Regular sanding paper will clog up rather quickly.

Drywall specific paper looks like this, and lasts longer and works better.

[image: sanding]

Then prime over it.

Comment: My only question is why the guy took a picture of drywall sandpaper while barefoot and wearing pajamas. Who does that???